# Algorithm for Getting Largest Connected Component From List of Touching Pairs

Tags: haskell, connected-components

I have a program which finds the touching pairs of a given value in a binary image. For example, consider the below image:

```hs
[
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

When the algorithm is run with a value of 0, it finds the following pairs:

```hs
[(1, 2), (22, 23), (23, 24), (18, 23)]
```

Is there an algorithm to find the largest connected components from these values? So for this example, it should return 4.

I know of some solutions which treat the [matrix as a graph and run a DFS on it](https://weirdo.dev/algorithms/largest-island-in-binary-matrix.html), but I'm looking for a solution using the already calculated connected pairs.

Comment: Using `Data.Graph.buildG` and `Data.Graph.components`:   `import Data.Graph`; `ccList = components $ buildG (0,25) [(1, 2), (22, 23), (23, 24), (18, 23)]
`; `maxByKey k = foldr1 (\x y -> if k x >= k y then x else y)`; then `maxByKey length ccList` will produce the largest connected component, in the form of a tree `Node {rootLabel = 18, subForest = [Node {rootLabel = 23, subForest = [Node {rootLabel = 22, subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = 24, subForest = []}]}]}`

Comment: Otherwise look for a package implementing [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_find), which is probably the best-suited algorithm for this.

Comment: @Stef you might want to write your union-find solution as a full answer instead of just a comment. This seems to be the solution required by the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I will elaborate the answer of @Stef from the comment.*

From what is given in the problem, it appears that you already have an existing algorithm to find the edges of the connected components. All you have to do now is build the components and determine the largest. As noted in the comment you can use [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for this.

In union-find, each element in your pair will be treated as a set. We assume here that in addition to the 3 union-find operations, we can also perform a `size()` operation to determine the size of each set. Now, for each element of each pair, perform `make-set()` and then perform a `union()`. A union of a pair is interpreted as combing the elements into the same component. Following a union, update the set that currently has the largest size if necessary. After performing all unions, you will now have the largest set, which is also the largest component.

Answer (score 1):

Create a graph only from nodes that appear in the output, and add an edge for each tuple in the output.

Then find the connected components in this graph using DFS + union find (or your other favorite method)